# Twitter OAuth token/secret generator

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have an PHP SDK for Twitter OAuth, but in it's constructor, I have to pass the OAuth secret and token, which I don't have. Usually I won't need this, because I am getting them by request (GET), but I need a set, to be able to test my script.

So, is there any (edit: **easy**) way I can get them? Maybe an online generator for it or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these details at https://dev.twitter.com/apps

Sign in and select your application, then somewere in your app settings they provide you with Oauth details for your own app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an application by following url https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
You can use it for your tests.